# Highcharts - Funnel, Line and Scatter

Tags: highcharts

I know it's relatively simple to combine graph types but was wondering if it the below was possible using HighCharts?

[image: Scatter and Line and Funnel]

Answer (score 1):

Well, very easy. You red lines would be a `scatter` type. Your line would be a `line`. Your funnel would be two `spline` types. You would need to calculate your curves for the splines however.

Comment: Thanks - I figured as much soon after I posted but presumed there would be a specific function that could help

Answer (score 0):

well you can do it with Highcharts. its as simple as it looks.

you can use a combination of spline and scatter chart.